# Are c_flags and obj-m special Makefile variables?

Tags: makefile, linux-kernel, kernel

In this [kbuild.mk](https://github.com/tsgates/rust.ko/blob/master/kbuild.mk) Makefile, I can see variables like `obj-m` and `c_flags`. Those haven't been initialized anywhere, yet get populated during the build. Are these some sort of special variables which get defined automatically in kernel Makefiles?

Comment: They get setup when the make configuration is run.

Comment: Where does it get set up here: https://github.com/tsgates/rust.ko/blob/master/Makefile?

Comment: That Makefile will include the config file, which is generated.  Most directories in the kernel will include a Makefile which will conditionally compile the files in that dir based on what was selected in the menu config.  I'm thinking `include ./config.mk` does this in the example you pointed to.

Comment: No, it doesn't. It just contains RUST_ROOT